# HTML 5 canvas key press time events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jquery-events

I am working on a [Stick Hero](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=stick%20hero) (famous Android game) clone in HTML 5, I am trying to implement the code for capturing the `time of key press (right arrow - ASCII 39)` in Javascript and grow a stick accordingly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Stuck Hero !</title>
    <script src='jquery-2.1.1.min.js'> </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id='stuck' height='300' width='500'> </canvas>
</body>
<script>

        var stick_size=10;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var canvas=$("#stuck")[0];
        var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
        var w=$("#stuck").width();
        var h=$("#stuck").height();
        var score=0;
        var stick=0;
        var timeout=0;

        console.log(w +" is width and "+h+" is the height ");
        paint(w,h,ctx);
        score_update(ctx);
        });


    function score_update(ctx){
        //function to print the score
        ctx.font = "20px Arial";
        ctx.strokeText("Your Score is :",1,300);
        console.log("Console Score Printed Successfully");
    }


    function paint(width,height,ctl) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
        ctx=ctl;
        // function to print different background styles
        if(rand %3 ==0) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#F0F0F0";
        }
        else if(rand %2 == 0){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#D0D0D0";
        }
        else{
            ctx.fillStyle = "#C0C0C0";
        }
        drawing(ctx,width,height);
        console.log("Console was Painted Successfully");
    }

    function drawing(ctx,width,height) {
        //filling rectangle
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);

        //drawing our hero
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(20, 200, 15 , 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fill();
        console.log("Shapes were drawn Successfully");
    }   

    //growing stick
    function grow_stick() {
        for(lv=200;lv>stick_size;lv++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(20,200);
            console.log("Moved to 20 , 200 in Canvas");
            ctx.lineTo(20,lv);
            console.log("Drawing Line from 20 to "+lv);
            ctx.stroke();           
            console.log("Stroke is Done");
        }
        console.log("Stick was growing Successfully");
    }

    function clearcanvas(ctl,width,height){
        //function to clear the screen data
        ctl.clearRect ( 0 , 0 ,width,height );
    }


    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == "39"){  //38 is the code for up key
            //event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Down key is pressed");
            timeout= setInterval(grow_stick);
        }

    }).bind('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.which == "39") {
        console.log("Down key pressed is released ");
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

I having some issues and clarification

1. **How to track key press event ?**
      I tried to set a timeout function when key is pressed and I will release the timeout function when the key is released (but having some issues with cleartimeout)
2. **How to not accept any events once the key is release , I have to do other animations ?**
   Not tried yet and have no idea
3. **Another Common Question**
   How to prepare my mindset as a HTML5 Game developer, any reference link or idea is welcomed, I know basic programming

Edit : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bnngd1d/)

Comment: Good question +1 Do you have a jsFiddle for us to inspect ?

Answer (score 1):

1. try to use Intervals like this:

   ```
   var myInt=null
   $(document).keydown(function(e){
        var key = e.which;
        if(key == "39"){  //38 is the code for up key
            //event.preventDefault();
            console.log("Down key is pressed");
            myInt = setInterval(function(){ myAnimation() }, 40); 
            //40 milliseconds because of 25 images per sec
        }
   }).bind('keyup', function(e){
       if(e.which == "39") {
           console.log("Down key pressed is released ");
           clearInterval(myInt);
       }

   function myAnimation(){
      //your animation that last 40 milliseconds
   }
   ```
2. you can set some kind of boolean in the keyeup event and check for it at every event with if (if(keyreleased==false){//do normal stuff}else{//skip})
   after your animation is done set the booleon back to default

   ```
   var keyreleased=false;
   .bind('keyup', function(e){
   keyreleased=true;
   }

   someEvent(){
        if(keyreleased!=true){
             //do stuff
        }
        //animation done
        keyreleased=false;
   }
   ```
3. i have no idea ^^

Comment: I want to grow the stick (drawing the line) , along with the user key press and hold , not after the user released the key and calucalate the time.

Comment: you can use var myInt=setInterval(function(){ //a part of your animation, e.g. grow a pixel or 2 in a specific timelength... i hope u know what i mean}, //milliseconds); and clearInterval(myVar);
set the interval at keypress and the clear interval at keyup
the interval milliseconds should be exactly the same like the animation will last, so it dont stuck